# Some clients cannot connect to Server 2008 R2 VPN

Tags: vpn

Have a server 2008 r2 setup as a VPN server.  We have created a windows group to control access to the VPN called vpn-users.  Clients are all Windows 7 Pro.

This all seems to work fine except some users cannot connect to the VPN! For example I try to logon to the VPN from a client and get an error saying the server refused the connect due to a policy in place. Specifically authentication type!  Fine I think.  So i drop that user into the vpn-users group created for this and try again and hey presto the user can now logon!  Great.

Now try this with another user.  But this time I get the same error even though I have dropped them into the vpn-users group!!

So does anyone have any idea why this works for some users and not for others??

I have tried moving the user from certain OU's in AD to others, copying the account, taking the user out of the vpn-users group and then back in but get the same error each time.

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the **Dial-In** tab for the on the user object within Active Directory.  I believe that if remote access been disabled for the user there they will not be able to connect.